# Close Or Disable Alert Message on Liferay 7

Tags: notifications, alert, liferay-7

How do I remove or disable the alert message that appears above right the page when request/response takes too long or the user session is ending?

[image]

[image]

I added the ff JavaScript inside AUI().ready(){} in main.js file of the theme;

```
$('.lfr-alert-container .close, .lfr-notification-container .close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hidden');
});
```

But this code only works to my custom SessionMessages/SessionErrors. The alert message does not respond.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please add following to `portal-ext.properties` :

```
session.timeout.warning=0
session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following property to `false` in your `portal-ext.properties`:

```
#
# Set this to true to enable Single Page Application links.
#

javascript.single.page.application.enabled=false
```

I know that the property name is a little bit confusing, but it will turn off the mentioned message and won't try to submit everything as AJAX.

Another option is to change the timeout:

```
#
# Set the timeout in milliseconds before SPA navigation times out and falls
# back to standard navigation.
#

javascript.single.page.application.timeout=0
```

The *session is ending* message is something different, which you can turn of with the following property:

```
#
# Specify the number of minutes before a warning is sent to the user
# informing the user of the session expiration. Specify 0 to disable any
# warnings.
#
session.timeout.warning=0
```

It helps to study `/liferay-src/portal-impl/src/portal.properties`, where you will find all options that you can configure with your `portal-ext.properties`. In addition since Liferay 7 some options are now configured with files in `liferay/osgi/configs` - if you look for classes annotated with `@ExtendedObjectClassDefinition` you should get an idea.

Comment: I added javascript.single.page.application.enabled=false to my portal-ext.properties. But still the error message appears and close icon/button won't work. I added screenshots to my post.